# Java Swing Custom Slider Image

Tags: java, swing, jslider

My program's GUI looks like this:
[I haven't unlocked image embedding yet sorry so has to be hyper link to imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdXU5.png)

How can I make the sliders look custom like this?
[slider I want to have in my gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIY1d.png)

Comment: `JSlider.setknobImage(ImageIO.read( new File( "d:\\d.jpg") );` Does this work?

Comment: @JFan I tried it and it didn't work, setKnobImage() doesn't seem to be a thing unless I need to import something.

Comment: You need to Import ImageIO an File

Comment: yes but for the actual setKnobImage call? ImageIO and File is just for getting the image.

Answer (score 0):

May be this may help you:-
Add this in your main method.

```
    Icon icon = new ImageIcon("slider.png");
    UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getDefaults();
    defaults.put("Slider.horizontalThumbIcon", icon);
```